# Using FIX protocol to connect to the broker

Tags: fix-protocol

I am currently trying to build a program using FIX protocol to communicate with a broker (currenex). I sent my (self-generated) logon message to the server and got something back.
This is what I sent

```
8=FIX.4.49=8835=A49=xxxxxxxx56=CNX34=152=20140718-11:40:18.24498=0108=30141=Y554=xxxxxx10=128
```

(the SenderCompID and the password were replaced)
and I got

```
8=FIX.4.49=7635=A34=149=CNX52=20140718-11:40:33.22456=xxxxxxxx141=Y98=0108=3010=1458=FIX.4.49=7035=h34=249=CNX52=20140718-11:40:33.22656=xxxxxxxx336=0340=210=128
```

back from the server.
I think I built the logon message correct (or did I?). But when I sent a second request MarketDataRequest

```
8=FIX.4.49=13735=V49=xxxxxxxx56=CNX34=252=20140718-11:42:53.504262=363263=1264=0265=1266=N267=2269=1269=0146=155=GBP/USD554=xxxx10=013
```

I had no response at all. I asked the broker and they said the connection dropped right away every time after I logged in.
I thought it was some connection problem and I tried using RESTClient (Postman) to send the message but the result was the same.
Could any one take a look at my messages and point out if there is something stupid please? 
All I need is the real-time exchange rate so a simple FIX message example will be very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Bo

Comment: I don't know what language you're using, but I think it's definitely worth your time to check out one of the QuickFIX engines.  You do not want to be implementing the low-level transport logic (heartbeats, reconnects, etc) yourself, because it sucks.  QF ports are available for C++, Java, C#, and Go.  The C++ port has Ruby and Python wrappers too.  There's also a JRuby gem "quickfix-jruby" that uses the Java port.

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for the comment. I am using LabVIEW to build the connection. I think I had one working now (not full feature of course). But I think you are right. If I move on using more feature I shall take a look at QuickFIX.

Comment: Hello Bo. Hoping you are using Ruby. Was wondering if you did move to QuickFIX and if it worked for you. Currently trying to use TCPSocket to open a connection... can not even that is working so thought of QuickFIX but very little help exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logon response message says that your trading session is open (340=2) so it's not broker-side problem. I think your program disconnects TCP/IP connection from server after login message. FIX protocol insists that TCP/IP connection must be kept alive during the whole FIX session - otherwise the session will be closed. So you need rewrite your program to keep connection alive and just send there yor requests and listen for responses. Don't close the connection.

Comment: Thank you, Konstantin. That sounds reasonable. I will try that and let you know the result. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I tried to keep the connection alive, and yes, I got the response message for MarketDataRequest. But the content is not what I expected. So this is what I received 
 8=FIX.4.49=7635=A34=149=CNX52=20140718-10:48:56.93556=xxxxxxxx141=Y98=0108=3010=1668=FIX.4.49=7035=h34=249=CNX52=20140718-10:48:56.93556=xxxxxxxx336=0340=210=147 
which is similar to the response of the logon message. Shall I expect the 34=3 and 34=4 messages? Really appreciate for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Feel free to ask it as separate question

Answer (score 0):

Try using Minifix tool which will maintain the heartbeats and the session connection.
Ideally for a 35=V request you should get 
35=W = Market Data-Snapshot/Full Refresh
35=X = Market Data-Incremental Refresh
35=Y = Market Data Request Reject

you get a 35=3 (reject) or 35=4 (or a seq reset) in response to a 35=A request.